# Django: Transaction and select_for_update()

Tags: python, django

In my Django application I have the following two models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def get_number_of_registered_tickets():
        return EventRegistration.objects.filter(event__exact=self).aggregate(total=Coalesce(Sum('number_tickets'), 0))['total']


class EventRegistration(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number_tickets = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

The method `get_number_of_registered_tickets()` do I need at several places in my application (e.g. template rendering). So I thought it makes sense to put it into the model also because it's related to it and I often heard it's good to have "fat models and lightweight views".

My problem now:
In order to prevent that two people want to register for the event *in parallel*, I have to use locking. Example: Let's say there's one ticket left to register for. Now, to people are on my website and click "Register" simultaneously. Under unforunate circumstances, it could happen that both requests are valid and now I have more registrations than capacity.

I'm relatively new to Django, but reading through the docs, I thought that [`select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) should be the solution, am I right here (I use PostgreSQL, so that should be supported)?

However, the docs also say that using `select_for_update()` is only valid within a transcation.

> Evaluating a queryset with `select_for_update()` in autocommit mode on
>   backends which support `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is a
>   [`TransactionManagementError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError) error because the rows are not locked in
>   that case. If allowed, this would facilitate data corruption and could
>   easily be caused by calling code that expects to be run in a
>   transaction outside of one.

My idea was now to change my model method `get_number_of_registered_tickets()` and add **select_for_update()**:

```
def get_number_of_registered_tickets():
        return EventRegistration.objects.select_for_update().filter(event__exact=self).aggregate(total=Coalesce(Sum('number_tickets'), 0))['total']
```

**Different questions now:**

1. Is using `select_for_update()` the right solution to my problem?
2. Does it mean that I cannot use the method `get_number_of_registered_tickets()` in different views/templates now, given that it seems to only work within a transaction? Do I have to violate DRY here and copy and paste the query with select_for_update() to another place in my code?
3. I tested it locally and Django does not raise the `TransactionManagementError` while being in autocommit mode (not using any transactions). What could be the reason or do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 9):

Doing `select_for_update()` on an `EventRegistration` queryset isn't the way to go. That locks the specified rows, but presumably the conflict you're trying to prevent involves creating *new* `EventRegistrations`. Your lock won't prevent that.

Instead you can acquire a lock on the `Event`. Something like:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    @transaction.atomic
    def reserve_tickets(self, number_tickets):
        list(Event.objects.filter(id=self.id).select_for_update())  # force evaluation
        if self.get_number_of_registered_tickets() + number_tickets <= self.capacity:
            # create EventRegistration
        else:
            # handle error
```

Note that this uses the [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) decorator to make sure you are running inside a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But would not it also work with `select_for_update()`? As far as I understand, it acquires exclusive locks on the specified rows. In order to register for the event, both requests have to check if tickets are available. However, the first one who acquires the lock, locks the other request (that request cannot check available seats then). Only when I commit, this request can go on and now the one ticket is already registered.

Comment: @Aliquis: You can only lock rows that actually exist. If there are no existing `EventRegistrations` for that `Event` and two requests come in that conflict, your approach won't stop them.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right and your approach seems to be the better one, thanks. Nonetheless, out of curiosity: Say there are already registrations and now two want to register the one ticket left. In that case, the `select_for_update()` approach should work, am I right here?

Comment: @Aliquis: Yes, that's right. But even if it worked flawlessly, it still wouldn't make sense to put in a read-only method like `get_number_of_registered_tickets()`. Let's say you have some other view that wants to show that number for informational purposes. You would end up needlessly locking those rows.

Comment: Does your `Event.objects.filter(id=self.id).select_for_update()` not also lock a lot? In my real model I have, of course, some more fields in my Event model (like start time, end time, etc.). When I want to display that, I cannot do that as long as the transaction for the reservation is running, right?

Comment: @Aliquis: No, acquiring a lock doesn't block reads. And the lock is only acquired when you actually want to make a reservation, not every time you want to count the number of tickets. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) on `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I tried your solution and the problem is that it does actually not lock because Django's QuerySet evaluation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: @Aliquis: OK, so evaluate it. More commonly you would do the `select_for_update()`  when you first fetch the `Event` (based on an `id` in the URL, or whatever), but this is the "fat models" version, since you mentioned that.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry if acquiring the lock does not actually block reads, how does you approach solve the race condition? the main point of the author's question is to block the read operation (and any consequent lines of code) until the current thread is done.

Comment: @A.Khaled: No, the OP's problem is this: "Under unfortunate circumstances, it could happen that both requests are valid and now I have more registrations than capacity." That is the race condition that this code prevents. Trying to block reads is almost never the right solution in database programming.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, @KevinChristopherHenry. Can you have a look at the latest question that I posted? it's very similar to this situation and I can't find a way to overcome it other than a read lock, it might hint at a bad design from my end, but I am not sure how to handle that too.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, also referring back to the author's situation and your suggested solution, I am still convinced that this will not solve the race condition, since there's no read lock, if 2 threads are evaluating the line of code at the if condition, and there's one ticket left, both threads will pass and move inside the body of the if condition, which is not the intended behavior, the correct way to solve this is for one thread to wait till the other thread has finished the whole transaction, and then it can start evaluating the line at the if condition

Comment: @A.Khaled: Only one thread can acquire the lock (for a given `Event`) at a time, so two threads can't get to the `if` condition at the same time. One will block on acquiring the lock. This code is basically doing what you're asking for, but it's not a "read lock", it's a [`SELECT FOR UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) lock.

Comment: Great, so is it always safe to assume that Django's select_for_update is a blocking statement? and its execution unblocks once the lock is freed? if that's the case then I might have over complicated things with my current design, I should just use your approach and I'll achieve what I need.

Comment: @A.Khaled: See the documentation I linked to for how the lock behaves in PostgreSQL, and note that other database engines could behave differently. I don't have time to look into your posted question at the moment, but my advice would be to give up on the idea of blocking reads and instead focus on making sure inconsistent data can't get committed to the database.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in multiple database environment you must have `atomic` and `select_for_update` on the same db, otherwise it wont work

```
with transaction.atomic(using='dbwrite'):
     Model.objects.using('dbwrite').select_for_update()....
```