# What happens when only 1 product available and 2 user clicks buy now

Tags: django

I am doing an online shopping site. I need to know that if only 1 stock available for a product and 2 user clicks buy now at same time. How to deal such a scenario

Comment: Please check this question [Django: Transaction and select_for_update()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52454982/django-transaction-and-select-for-update)

Comment: compare if number of products in user's basket or selection is higher than product availability or stock and return a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is pretty much strait forward that Only one User will have access to the product that's for sure, Now you can validate using exceptions like if User have product or not. If user have it than he can proceed and checkout the product. If not than "The product sold out". Now it is also True that there will be only one user which will have hold on the product. So you can also check it when user checkout for product.

You might want to add some more information about the question here.

Comment: Brother my doubt is that if only one stock available and 2 users at the same time hit buy now button, which user gets the product